# Behavior of break statement

Tags: c, loops, break, control-structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    i = j = 0;
    clrscr();

    for(k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        printf("Flag A\t");

        for(l = 0; l < 2; l++)         
        { 
            printf("Flag B\t");
            if(i == 5)
            {
                printf("Flag C\t");

                if(j == 5)
                {
                    printf("Flag D\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf("Value of i=%d,j=%d,k=%d,l=%d", i, j, k, l);
    getch();
}
```

When I trace the output of above code, it is:

```
Flag A Flag B Flag B Flag A Flag B Flag B Flag A Flag B Flag B Flag C Flag D 

values of i=5 j=5 k=3 l=1
```

I get the same answer manually. Also, my question is: when I trace the output, the break condition occurs when i=5 and j=5. At that time, control breaks two `if` loops and the `l` `for` loop, and gets started from the next iteration of the `k` `for` loop. Is that the regular behavior of the `break` (cracks 3 nested loops when it is nested inside 3 loops), or does it happen due to the combination of the loops? What happens if I use other possible combinations of the loops? Please explain behavior of the `break` statement when it's used with multiple combinations of other loops. Please explain behavior with `switch` also.

Comment: Read a good C programming book. Compile your code with warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`), then **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run it step by step.

Comment: There's only 2 loops in your code, IDK what you are talking about with "3 nested loops". `break` breaks out of the innermost loop only. Also, your indentation is horrible

Comment: "two if loops" `if` is **not** a loop. `break` only affects **one** loop, the `for`.

Comment: Better consult a C programming tutorial.

Comment: @Basile- please suggest any complete reference in which concepts like this are elaborated well. i am confused

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/books/c.html but also read again the lecture notes of the courses you are following

Comment: @SumeetBajiraoGaikwad I'm under impression that you're using _Turbo/Borland C_ ? If you're please don't decade old compiler.

Comment: Try using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) instead ...

Answer (score 2):

Note that `if` is not considered a loop. Rather it is a decision structure.

The only loops you have in this example are the two `for` loops. The `break` will stop the execution of the inner-most `for` loop.

Comment: @ code-apprentice-I assume while,do while & switch are also loops & if is the decision making statement ??

Comment: @SumeetBajiraoGaikwad `switch` is not a loop. The word "loop" implies a repetition of some kind. Neither `if` nor `switch` cause a repetition. Only `for`, `while`, and `do...while` are repeating structures and therefore the only flavors of loops in C.